# how to use wget to generate constant workload on server

Tags: load, webserver, wget, workload

Hey folks,
I want to generate a constant workload on a server - so it utilizes a certain amount of CPU on my node. I tried doing this in a script by repeatedly fetching the homepage of my webapp in a loop 'n' times. However, this does not generate a constant workload, instead the workload continuously varies..Is there any way to generate a constant workload using wget by writing some kind of a script? What kind of scripts can i write using 'wget'?

Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 1):

I'm using [JMeter](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/) for these kind of problems. You just have to find the right amount of threads that should be running.

Comment: thanks.. this tool is useful.. but I am connecting to a  remote server via ssh terminal and I wont be able to run the gui... can i use this to send requests from command line without the request sender GUI?

Comment: JMeter can run in a terminal directly.  It's a good tool to learn.

Answer (score 0):

If JMeter is too involved for what you need, [ab](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/ab.html) is a simpler alternative that's very easy to get started with (but of course isn't in the same league as JMeter feature-wise).

Comment: I tried using ab - but when I ran the default 'ab' of my webserver I got the following error - ab: error while loading shared libraries:..What could be the reason? Thanks!

Comment: That's a problem with you apache install - try rebuilding.